# Wordpress Cookies via functions.php doesn't read cookie until page re-load?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress and have created a cookie in functions.php.

My problem is that this cookie is not read by the template/page when it's created but on it's 2nd page load.

Is there a workaround to this so I can read the cookie when it's created?

Here is my current code at functions.php:

```
<?php
function my_cookie() {
$myvalue = 'hello'; 
if (!isset($_COOKIE['myCookie'])) {
  setcookie("myCookie", $myvalue, time()+3600, "/", ".mydomain.com");
global $myglobal;
$_COOKIE['myCookie'] = $myglobal;

}
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_cookie');
?>
```

Comment: Try passing the same data directly to `$_COOKIE` when you set it. That way you have access to it through `$_COOKIE` without the page reload, then on subsequent loads, it'll be there anyway.

Comment: please see code above....that's what I tried but couldn't call is back from my main page

Comment: Can you elaborate more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the cookie from the file index.php. This is the first file that runs when you start your site and so the cookie should then be available by the time you get to the main page.

Comment: Wordpress will only allow me to set the cookie in Functions.php so as far as I know I cannot do this

Comment: Its open source, you can do what you want with it, If your getting an error there must be an error with your code. (dont use the wordpress function, create your own)

Comment: What I mean is that wordpress does not create cookies outside functions.php ... i've tried and it won't work.

Comment: That's because you are using a wordpress function to create it, create your own.

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. When using PHP to create a cookie, it does not also set the super global found in $_COOKIE. The cookie header has been sent and the cookie is set however.

The $_COOKIE super global on the other hand is set on page load by any cookies sent from the browser in its initial page request.

So when you set a cookie and it is sent to the browser and saved on the client side, the next request the browser sends to the server will also send along this previously saved cookie, which will set the $_COOKIE super global.

If you want to save changes made to the cookies server side, you can either create a class which stores the original cookies, then modifies them when you make changes to cookies through the class's cookie changing methods, then use the same class to retrieve any cookie data, or you can modify the $_COOKIE super global yourself at the same time you set the actual cookie with PHP.

Answer (score 3):

I like to save my search criteria to cookies to help prevent issues when a user tries to back out of a page and gets a "Would you like to resubmit?" message, so I set my cookies like the following, which allows me to use them on the first page load:

```
// Set cookie of posted values
add_action( 'init', 'set_new_cookie' );

function set_new_cookie()
{
    $COOKIE_NAME = 'my_cookie_name';

    $name     = $COOKIE_NAME;
    $expire   = LIFETIME;
    $path     = COOKIEPATH;
    $domain   = COOKIEDOMAIN;
    $secure   = false;
    $httponly = false;

    if ( $_POST )
    {
        $POST = array(
            'variable1' => $_POST['variable1'],
            'variable2' => $_POST['variable2'],
            'variable3' => $_POST['variable3'],
            'variable4' => $_POST['variable4']
        );

        foreach( $POST AS $key => $value )
        {
            // Set the cookie
            setcookie( $name."[$key]", $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly );

            // Set the $_COOKIE global to have access to value on first page load
            $_COOKIE[$name][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then have imediate access to:

```
print_r( @$_COOKIE['my_cookie_name'] );
```